# SQL Query Asking for Count & Total

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm linked to a database and asked to complete the following query. The customer id, company name, number of orders, and total order amount for all customers who purchased an item in the Meat/Poultry category. This is what I have so far but keep getting errors. Most of the questions are well above the class level but i'm working through as much on my own as possible. Been using code from previous question to aid me. Not sure if it is correct.

```
WITH CTE AS (

SELECT Customers.CustomerID, 
   Customers.CompanyName,
   Categories.CategoryName,
   COUNT(OrderID) AS total_orders,
   SUM(Quantity * UnitPrice) AS grand_total
   rn=ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Orders.OrderID)
FROM   Customers INNER JOIN
   Orders ON Orders.OrderID=Orders.CustomerID INNER JOIN
[Order Details] ON Orders.OrderID=[Order Details].OrderID
WHERE (Categories.CategoryName)= 'Meat/Poultry'

Group BY Orders.OrderID,
 Customers.CompanyName,
     Categories.CategoryName
)

SELECT  A.CustomerID,
A.CompanyName,
    A.total_orders,
A.grand_total,
(SELECT SUM(grand_total), COUNT(total_orders))
FROM CTE B
WHERE   B.grand_total > A.grand_total) RunningTotal
FROM CTE A
ORDER BY RunningTotal
```

Can SQL queries be broken down and combined later? I was thinking maybe this would make it simpler to code. Are there methods or tools to assist a very beginner other than what I use so far?

thanks,

Comment: You need to group by customerID, not OrderID, or show OrderID not CustomerID in the SELECT list, or explain which customer you want shown...

Comment: Tried changing the grouping but still getting errors. What I'm looking for is to output the CustomerID, CustomerName, OrderID and total number of order and total cost for customers who bought something from Meat/Poultry category. Should I repost my code with updates?

Comment: Make a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3) with sample data and desired results. Posting more code isn't going to help, and adding more word problems won't help either.

Comment: My apologies, I didn't even realize what a SQL Fiddle was until I looked it up. Well above my knowledge and abilities. Will have to learn to be proficient at that in the future. Our only guide thus far has been the text book and whatever we can search on the web. Thanks for the help anyhoot.

Comment: It's just an online place where you can issue CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements so we understand your table, data, and the results you want out of it. What version of SQL Server? Also how is the Categories table related to anything? The join is customers -> orders -> order details. How do we know the category? That table is not mentioned as part of the join.

Comment: And what is "total order amount for all customers who purchased an item in that category"? Total for all orders by customers who have ever purchased at least one item in that category? Total for all orders by customer where at least one item in each order is from that category? Total for all products from that category only, by customer, across all orders? The ambiguity demonstrates why word problems can be ok, but usually require more info. Whereas posting sample data and showing desired results is far less likely to be ambiguous at all (though edge cases are usually still "forgotten").

Comment: I'll try and answer the best I know how. The results should display CustomerID(from Customers Table), CompanyName (from Customers Table) and CategoryName(from Categories Table). Thought it would be good to add OrderID(from Orders Table) as a reference to count the total # of orders. The last column should list a total order amount for all the customers who bought from the specific category. Been working on solving using Access design view. Oh, I have SQL 2008 R2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a few guesses at your schema when constructing [this SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/65c62a/1). I also constructed two different queries because I find this requirement ambiguous:

> The customer id, company name, number of orders, and total order amount for all customers who purchased an item in the Meat/Poultry category.

The sum of only meat/poultry products, across all orders, by customer:

```
SELECT 
  c.CustomerID, c.CompanyName,
  OrderCount = COUNT(DISTINCT od.OrderID),
  [Meat/Poultry Total] = SUM(od.Quantity * od.UnitPrice)
FROM dbo.Customers AS c
INNER JOIN dbo.Orders AS o
ON c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
INNER JOIN dbo.OrderDetails AS od
ON o.OrderID = od.OrderID
INNER JOIN dbo.Products AS p
ON od.ProductID = p.ProductID
INNER JOIN dbo.Categories AS cat
ON p.CategoryID = cat.CategoryID
WHERE cat.CategoryName = 'Meat/Poultry'
GROUP BY c.CustomerID, c.CompanyName;
```

The sum of all orders where at least one item in each order was meat/poultry (by customer):

```
SELECT
  c.CustomerID, c.CompanyName,
  OrderCount = COUNT(DISTINCT o.OrderID),
  GrandTotal = SUM(od.Quantity * od.UnitPrice)
FROM dbo.Customers AS c
INNER JOIN dbo.Orders AS o
ON c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
INNER JOIN dbo.OrderDetails AS od
ON o.OrderID = od.OrderID
WHERE EXISTS
(
  SELECT 1 FROM dbo.OrderDetails AS od2
    INNER JOIN dbo.Products AS p
    ON p.ProductID = od2.ProductID
    INNER JOIN dbo.Categories AS cat
    ON p.CategoryID = cat.CategoryID
    WHERE cat.CategoryName = 'Meat/Poultry'
    AND od2.OrderID = o.OrderID
)
GROUP BY c.CustomerID, c.CompanyName;
```

Notice customer #3 never enters any of these results...

Comment: I like what you have here. Are those variables in the SELECT statements (OrderCount, Grandtotal)? Also the keyword EXISTS. Don't see that on the tutorial W3Schools I use. If I wanted do display the Meat/Poultry Category in results would that be added to GROUP BY or is it required in SELECT statements as well? Sorry for all the questions.

Comment: @allendks45 No, those are not variables (in T-SQL, variables are denoted by an `@` prefix, e.g. `@CustomerID`). Don't use W3schools to learn T-SQL (see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87678/) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120025/)). Get a copy of [Itzik Ben-Gan's Fundamentals book](http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/0735626014) - you should be able to find pretty cheap used 2008 copies now. Since you already know the category, you can just add it as a constant to the `SELECT` list, e.g. `,Category='Meat/Poultry'`.

Comment: Okay, again thanks. That is surprising about the resource I was using. This site is amazing and everyone is very helpful. Certainly wish I were good enough to answer questions and help too. Maybe in the future...well into the future. Book is next on list.